# Any method for measuring hydroxyl and hydroperoxyl radicals in water?

Tags: water, radiation, physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, ions

I am looking to irradiate water containing some amounts of iron and would like to measure the amount of hydroperoxyl and hydroxyl radicals produced in real time as a result of the irradiation. Is there any way to do so without very expensive equipment such as an EPR machine?

Comment: Colorimetric analysis such as [this](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC9964436/) or [this](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00604-019-3488-4) perhaps? You might be better off asking this on the [Chemistry Stack Exchange](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/).